# Failed building wheels for numba/llvmlite

Tags: python, linux, llvm, numba, llvmlite

I am trying to install ddsp using `pip3 install ddsp` using venv.
I have installed the needed dependencies for ddsp, I installed numba and llvmlite succesfully, but when I try to install ddsp I get the following output after a while:

```
    Building wheels for collected packages: numba, llvmlite
      Building wheel for numba (setup.py) ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [919 lines of output]
          /tmp/pip-install-vwar_wlk/numba_9bda532cbe9d4d8886cb806387be79c2/setup.py:94: DeprecationWarning:
          
            `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
            of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
            Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
            It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
            For more details, see:
              https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html
          
          
            import numpy.distutils.misc_util as np_misc
          TBB not found
          OpenMP disabled
          /home/lonskyne/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py:80: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
          !!
          
                  ********************************************************************************
                  Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
                  If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
                  ********************************************************************************
          
          !!
            dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
          running bdist_wheel
          running build
          got version from file /tmp/pip-install-vwar_wlk/numba_9bda532cbe9d4d8886cb806387be79c2/numba/_version.py {'version': '0.49.1', 'full': 'd2cac8597ad2aa4074147d9c7595f5b5e9919901'}
          running build_py
          creating build
          creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
          creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/numba
          copying numba/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/numba
...
          copying numba/cuda/tests/cudadrv/data/jitlink.ptx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/numba/cuda/tests/cudadrv/data
          running build_ext
          building 'numba._dynfunc' extension
          Warning: Can't read registry to find the necessary compiler setting
          Make sure that Python modules winreg, win32api or win32con are installed.
          INFO: C compiler: gcc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python/src=/usr/src/debug/python -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python/src=/usr/src/debug/python -flto=auto -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python/src=/usr/src/debug/python -flto=auto -fPIC
          
          creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
          creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/numba
          INFO: compile options: '-I/home/lonskyne/.venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c'
          extra options: '-g'
          INFO: gcc: numba/_dynfuncmod.c
          INFO: gcc -shared -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -flto=auto -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -flto=auto build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/numba/_dynfuncmod.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/numba/_dynfunc.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
          building 'numba._dispatcher' extension
          INFO: C compiler: gcc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python/src=/usr/src/debug/python -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python/src=/usr/src/debug/python -flto=auto -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python/src=/usr/src/debug/python -flto=auto -fPIC
          
          creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/numba/core
          creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/numba/core/typeconv
          INFO: compile options: '-I/home/lonskyne/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/lonskyne/.venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c'
          INFO: gcc: numba/_dispatcher.c
          INFO: gcc: numba/_dispatcherimpl.cpp
          INFO: gcc: numba/_hashtable.c
          INFO: gcc: numba/_typeof.c
          INFO: gcc: numba/core/typeconv/typeconv.cpp
          numba/_dispatcher.c: In function ‘call_trace’:
          numba/_dispatcher.c:26:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘use_tracing’; did you mean ‘tracing’?
             26 |     tstate->use_tracing = 0;
                |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
                |             tracing
          numba/_dispatcher.c:28:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘use_tracing’; did you mean ‘tracing’?
             28 |     tstate->use_tracing = ((tstate->c_tracefunc != NULL)
                |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
                |             tracing
          numba/_dispatcher.c: In function ‘call_cfunc’:
          numba/_dispatcher.c:303:17: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘use_tracing’; did you mean ‘tracing’?
            303 |     if (tstate->use_tracing && tstate->c_profilefunc)
                |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
                |                 tracing
          numba/_dispatcher.c:340:17: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘frame’; did you mean ‘cframe’?
            340 |         tstate->frame = frame;
                |                 ^~~~~
                |                 cframe
          numba/_dispatcher.c:71:32: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘frame’; did you mean ‘cframe’?
             71 |                tstate, tstate->frame, PyTrace_CALL, cfunc))     \
                |                                ^~~~~
          numba/_dispatcher.c:341:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘C_TRACE’
            341 |         C_TRACE(result, fn(PyCFunction_GET_SELF(cfunc), args, kws));
                |         ^~~~~~~
          numba/_dispatcher.c:82:50: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘frame’; did you mean ‘cframe’?
             82 |                                  tstate, tstate->frame,         \
                |                                                  ^~~~~
          numba/_dispatcher.c:341:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘C_TRACE’
            341 |         C_TRACE(result, fn(PyCFunction_GET_SELF(cfunc), args, kws));
                |         ^~~~~~~
          numba/_dispatcher.c:90:44: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘frame’; did you mean ‘cframe’?
             90 |                            tstate, tstate->frame,               \
                |                                            ^~~~~
          numba/_dispatcher.c:341:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘C_TRACE’
            341 |         C_TRACE(result, fn(PyCFunction_GET_SELF(cfunc), args, kws));
                |         ^~~~~~~
          numba/_dispatcher.c:344:17: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘frame’; did you mean ‘cframe’?
            344 |         tstate->frame = frame->f_back;
                |                 ^~~~~
                |                 cframe
          numba/_dispatcher.c:344:30: error: invalid use of incomplete typedef ‘PyFrameObject’ {aka ‘struct _frame’}
            344 |         tstate->frame = frame->f_back;
                |                              ^~
          numba/_dispatcher.c: In function ‘Dispatcher_call’:
          numba/_dispatcher.c:512:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘use_tracing’; did you mean ‘tracing’?
            512 |     if (ts->use_tracing && ts->c_profilefunc) {
                |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
                |             tracing
          numba/_dispatcher.c: In function ‘call_cfunc’:
          numba/_dispatcher.c:354:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
            354 | }
                | ^
          error: Command "gcc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python/src=/usr/src/debug/python -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python/src=/usr/src/debug/python -flto=auto -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python/src=/usr/src/debug/python -flto=auto -fPIC -I/home/lonskyne/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/lonskyne/.venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c numba/_dispatcher.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/numba/_dispatcher.o" failed with exit status 1
          [end of output]
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for numba
      Running setup.py clean for numba
      Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py) ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [15 lines of output]
          running bdist_wheel
          /home/lonskyne/.venv/bin/python3 /tmp/pip-install-vwar_wlk/llvmlite_32b3722ce4c9449090e8462db3ca8d58/ffi/build.py
          LLVM version... 16.0.6
          
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "/tmp/pip-install-vwar_wlk/llvmlite_32b3722ce4c9449090e8462db3ca8d58/ffi/build.py", line 192, in <module>
              main()
            File "/tmp/pip-install-vwar_wlk/llvmlite_32b3722ce4c9449090e8462db3ca8d58/ffi/build.py", line 182, in main
              main_posix('linux', '.so')
            File "/tmp/pip-install-vwar_wlk/llvmlite_32b3722ce4c9449090e8462db3ca8d58/ffi/build.py", line 144, in main_posix
              raise RuntimeError(msg)
          RuntimeError: Building llvmlite requires LLVM 7.0.x, 7.1.x or 8.0.x, got '16.0.6'. Be sure to set LLVM_CONFIG to the right executable path.
          Read the documentation at http://llvmlite.pydata.org/ for more information about building llvmlite.
          
          error: command '/home/lonskyne/.venv/bin/python3' failed with exit code 1
          [end of output]
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for llvmlite
      Running setup.py clean for llvmlite
    Failed to build numba llvmlite
    ERROR: Could not build wheels for numba, llvmlite, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I am using Arch Linux and python 3.11.6.
I have tried using `--use-pep517` when installing with pip3.
My installed numba version is 0.58.1
My instlled llvmlite version is 0.41.1
I am also using the latest llvm version in the pacman repos: llvm-16.0.6-1

Comment: Installing the dependencies separately may often not work: if the dependencies don't match the version numbers as set by ddsp, then pip will download the matching dependencies and try to install them. That is what you're seeing here, as far as I can tell: Numba is already installed, but pip tries to install it again (presumably a different version that what's installed).

Comment: If I go the ddsp homepage/GitHub repository, I can't find Numba or LLVMLite mentioned as dependencies. I do see tensorflow <= 2.11. [Tensorflow 2.11 on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.11.0/) shows, for starters, Python 3.10 as maximum allowed version. I can't the Numba and LLVMLite versions for Tensorflow 2.11 (it seems Tensorflow has its own way to do its installation).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think that is the problem because the two versions conflict or are you saying that me installing numba/pip seperately does not mean anything. Before installing them manually, first time I just ran install ddsp without numba/llvmlite present.

Comment: So you might be a bit stuck, unless the ddsp authors release the limits on the Tensorflow version. Alternatively, you could  download the most recent version of ddsp, adjust the requirements, and install it yourself from a local source.

Comment: "first time I just ran install ddsp without numba/llvmlite present": that should be the way to do it. I assume you ran into the same error as you have now, which is probably why you installed numba & llvmlite yourself first?

Comment: @9769953 Correct, I got the same errors the first time around.

Comment: @9769953 Is installing the older 2.11 version of tensorflow not an option here?

Comment: Yes, so you could try the following: clone the repository (possibly with --depth=1 for faster download, since you only want the latest), remove the limit on the Tensorflow dependency in `setup.py` and try yourself with a local `pip install .` or `python setup.py build; python setup.py install`. But, you may want to first install Tensorflow as well, as a dependency, before doing that, so you know Tensorflow is properly installed (assuming Tensorflow is the package wanting Numba & LLVMLite; that's possibly somewhere earlier in the output from pip that you have currently).

Comment: "Is installing the older 2.11 version of tensorflow not an option here?": I don't know. I guess it will not use your Numba and/or LLVMLite installations, but download its own specific Numba and LLVMLite packages, which fail to install, as is now. But that is a bit guesswork, since I can't really see why Numba and LLVMLite are required and installed by pip in the first place.

Comment: Question: how did you install Numba and LLVMLite yourself?

Comment: Your comments led me to the solution of my problem. I posted the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use Python 3.10 by installing the python310 AUR package and then installing ddsp using `python3.10 -m pip install ddsp` in the venv.